# Qt - copy a table from one database to another

Tags: database, sqlite, qt

I'm trying to copy table data from one database to another using this command:

`INSERT INTO database2.table2 SELECT * from database1.table1`

But I run into an error.

I have two databases called database1.db and database2.db

Here's my code:

```
database1_path = "/home/user/Desktop/database1.db";
database2_path = "/home/user/Documents/database2.db";

{
    QSqlDatabase db1 = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db1.setDatabaseName(database1_path);

    QSqlDatabase db2 = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db2.setDatabaseName(database2_path);

    if(!db1.open() && !db2.open())
    {
        qDebug() << "databases are NOT open!";
    }
    else
    {
        QString insert = QString("INSERT INTO '/home/user/Desktop/database1.db'.table1 SELECT * FROM '/home/user/Documents/database2.db'.table2;");

        QSqlQuery query(insert, db1);

        if(!query.exec(insert))
        {
            qDebug() << "Error:" << query.lastError().text();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the error I get:

> Error: "no such table: /home/user/Desktop/database1.db.table1 Unable to execute statement"

I also tried:
`"INSERT INTO database1.table1 SELECT * FROM database2.table2;"`

and:
`"INSERT INTO db1.table1 SELECT * FROM db2.table2;"`

But the same error occurred...

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot open two databases with two different connection and references the other one from another connection. For your use case you need to use the `attach` command in sql, so that your connection can references both databases.

```sql
ATTACH DATABASE '/home/user/Documents/database2.db' AS second_database;
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM second_database.table2;
```

Of course that assume that both database/table have compatible schema.